# How Table Can Be Emptied Which Has Got Related Column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

I use MSSQL 2012 Express..

There is two tables and they are related between two columns.. Suddenly one table is empty.. It happened 3 or more times.. How it can be possible?? I can't delete all rows on this table because of relation..

Answer (score 2):

But in all seriousness - Data won't just fall out of SQL Server. If you define an explicit foreign key relationship perhaps the process that is doing these deletes will die with an error message about the foreign key relationship. And like FreshPrince says, looking at logs, doing a trace, looking for triggers and watching what goes on will show you your culprit in due time. Also check for any "clean up" jobs.